# How to use auto_ptr in this case

Tags: c++, memory-management, auto-ptr

I have the following code:

```
void do_something(Image *image)
{

    Image *smoothed = NULL;
    Image *processed = NULL;
    if (condition_met) {
        smoothed = smooth(image);
        processed = smoothed;
    }
    else {
        processed = image;
    }

    ...
    delete smoothed_image
}
```

I was wondering if I can do the following and if this is the correct way. I am confused about setting another pointer from an auto_ptr object and whether that changes the ownership somehow.

```
void do_something(Image *image)
{
    auto_ptr<Image *> smoothed;
    Image *processed = NULL;

    if (condition_met) {
        smoothed = smooth(image); // This should own the pointer returned by smooth
        processed = smoothed; // Is this OK? processed is not an auto_ptr
    }
    else {
        processed = image;
    }

    ...
    // Destructor for the 'smoothed' variable should be called.
    // The 'image' variable is not deleted.
}
```

Will the destructor get called as I intend it and is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: it should be `auto_ptr<Image> smoothed;` and you should probably use `smoothed.reset(new_value);` to set and `smoothed.get()` to get the pointer that is owned by the `auto_ptr`. Also, `auto_ptr` should not be used anymore if at all possible, if you can use `unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: @Luca  Where is smoothed_image declared?

Comment: @PeterT why write an answer as a comment?

Comment: @Vlad: I made the correction.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the suggestions. I am using auto_ptr as I am not sure of using C++ 11 features yet in my code but you are right, I will make a switch to unique_ptr at some point.

Comment: @Luca even using `boost::unique_ptr` in non-C++11 code seems like a better solution. The semantics of `auto_ptr` are confusing. "Move on copy" is just a ridiculous thing to do.

Comment: @PeterT The practical semantics of `std::auto_ptr` are almost the same as those of `std::unique_ptr`; they both do a form of "move on copy" (which while somewhat surprising at first, is very practical in some cases).

Comment: @JamesKanze well, you simply can't copy a `std::unique_ptr`, so to move it, you need to actually use move-semantics.

Comment: @PeterT Yes.  But in almost all of the cases where you'd actually use an `std::unique_ptr`, the move semantics will be automatic (or not used at all---in a lot of cases, `std::unique_ptr` or `std::auto_ptr` are never moved or copied at all).  If you're sure that all targeted compilers support `std::unique_ptr`, by all means use it; it's future safe.  Otherwise, however, using `std::auto_ptr` is no big deal.

Comment: @JamesKanze: No, `unique_ptr` does a "move on move", which is just as practical but not surprising.

Comment: @JamesKanze Oh, I agree, if it's just in some local scope, it's not a big deal (but even there you could copy it twice by passing it as a parameter to 2 functions or something, so why take the risk, when there's no reason to). But especially when you're starting to make it a data-member or a template parameter of a container, then the semantics are waaaay surprising.

Comment: Unfortunately, using boost is not an option for my work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points to make.  Assuming that the signature of the smooth function is

```
Image* smooth(Image*);
```

Then your code would minimally have to be changed to

```
void do_something(Image *image)
{
    auto_ptr<Image> smoothed;
    Image *processed = NULL;

    if (condition_met) {
      smoothed.reset(smooth(image)); // This should own the pointer returned by smooth
      processed = smoothed.get(); // Maybe?  Depends on what you're doing
    }
    else {
      processed = image;
    }
```

It's reasonable in some cases to pull the raw pointer out of a smart pointer as is done in by `smoothed.get()` above, but you have to understand that as written the pointer held by **smoothed** will be deleted at the end of the function, even though you've done something else with the raw pointer.  Not enough information here to see if that's a problem, but it's a smell.

**std::auto_ptr** is now deprecated in favor of **std::unique_ptr**.  The big reason for this is the way the contents of auto_ptr are moved:

```
std::auto_ptr<int> a = new int(5);
std::auto_ptr<int> b = a;  // Copy?  No!
```

In this code the pointer held by a has been transferred to b.  **a** is no longer holding anything.  This runs counter to how we usually think of copy behavior so it's easy to mess up.

C++11 introduced the concept of r-value references (there are loads of articles around the net explaining this, including [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)).  Having r-value references allows **unique_ptr** to prevent data from being moved where it doesn't make sense.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> a = new(5);
std::unique_ptr<int> b = a; // Compile fail.  Not copyable
std::unique_ptr<int> c = std::move(a); // OK, shows intent
```

With this available, it would be possible to update your smooth() function signature to

```
std::unique_ptr<Image> smooth(Image*) {
  ...
  return newImage;
}
```

Which clearly instructs the caller that they should take ownership of of the returned pointer.  Now you can say

```
unique_ptr<Image> smoothed;
...
smoothed = smooth(image);
```

Because a value returned from a function is an r-value (not bound to a variable yet), the pointer is safely moved to **smoothed**.

In the end, yes, using a smart pointer is preferable to calling **delete**.  Just think through your design and try to be clear about pointer ownership.

Comment: How about linking to the [c++-faq] entry on [move semantics here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/256138)?